# How to get constant uid/gid on the NFS server for all created files

Tags: nfs

Is it possible to choose a particular UID/GID (of the server) for all the files that are going to be created/modified by NFS clients regardless of the client UID/GID?

For instance I'm sharing my Plex library as an NFS point and I want all the files people add to it from NFS client to be owned by `plex` user on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Is the NFS server running Linux? If so check out the `all_squash` and `anonuid` options in your `/etc/exports` file. (You might want to add `anongid` option too..)

From the `exports(5)` man page:

```
       all_squash
              Map all uids and gids to the anonymous user. Useful for NFS-exported public FTP directories, news spool
              directories, etc. The opposite option is no_all_squash, which is the default setting.

       anonuid and anongid
              These options explicitly set the uid and gid of the anonymous account.  This option is primarily useful
              for  PC/NFS  clients, where you might want all requests appear to be from one user.
```

The `all_squash` option will force all requests from NFS clients to run as a single user (`nobody` by default) and the `anonuid`/`anongid` options will let you change the user/group from `nobody` to something else.

So you probably want to use something like the following in your `/etc/exports` file:

```
/path/to/plex/directory   *(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1234,anongid=1234)
```

Note: change 1234 as needed for the numeric UID/GID of your `plex` user. (Or maybe you can just use the username? I'm not sure. I've only tried using numeric UIDs.) Also, you probably don't want to use the `*` wildcard entry; you should limit your exports to specific hosts (or at the very least limit it to your local subnet). I just used it here for an easy generic example.

With NFS 4 you could also use idmapd to do UID mapping but that's overkill for this use case.

If the server isn't running Linux you'll have to check the documentation for your system. The above export options are specific to the Linux version of NFS and may not apply on other implementations.